# Sum of numbers in multilevel list - Prolog

Tags: recursion, prolog, sum

I want to write a predicate in prolog which sums the numbers in all levels of a multilevel list. I get the error: `Arithmetic: deepSumList(_G5686,_G5697) is not a function`. 
The code is below :

```
deepSumList([],0).
deepSumList([H|T],Sum) :-
   (  is_list(H),
      deepSumList(T,X),
      Sum is X + deepSumList(H,Sum)
   ;  deepSumList(T,X),
      Sum is H + X
   ).
```

Comment: You can't do `Sum is X + deepSumList(H,Sum)`. 
Prolog doesn't work that way. 

Better would be:
`deepSumList(H, SumDeep), Sum is X + SumDeep`

Comment: @Ruben Thank you! You can post it as an answer so I can accept it , if you like :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So to give a bit more explanation:
Prolog always checks *whether something is considered TRUE* according to it's KB. So `Sum is X + deepSumList(H,Sum)` is more of a Java/Prolog mix. You ask Prolog if Sum can be instantiated by whatever `X + deepSumList(H,Sum)` is. And it doesn't know this because it doesn't know what to do with that last part.

Better would be:
`deepSumList(H, SumDeep), Sum is X + SumDeep`

First you make Prolog assign `SumDeep` with the 'Sum of the deeper lists' by recursion, then you assign `Sum` to the arithmetic answer of `X + SumDeep`.